# Using Regex to analyse Strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I created a simple quiz program and I am trying to figure out a method to return 3 types of answer's using regex. The 3 answers would be either fully correct, correct (but spelling error) and partially correct, but still awarded being correct.

So for an example, the three strings will be correct from the method comparing to the String "Elephants" : 1. "Elephants", 2. "Elephents", 3. "Elephant".

The 1st string is fully correct, so would return "Correct Answer".

The 2nd string is correct but spelling error ('a' instead of an 'e'), so will return "Correct although spelled Elephants".

The 3rd string is partially correct (No 's' at the end), but will return "Answer accepted"

Could anyone figure out the three types of Regex expressions I could use for this method?

Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for your job. You probably should use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Take a look at [levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Apache commons library StringUtils class has an implementation

Comment: Thanks for your replies, yes I'l look into that algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no regex solution for this, but you can implement a "distance algorithm" to measure the relative similarity of two words. One very common algorithm for this is [*Levenshtein Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), or Edit Distance: it tells you how many "editing actions" it would take to go from the answer the user typed in to the correctly spelled answer. Replacing, inserting, or deleting a symbol counts as one action. If the distance is two or less, the answer the user typed in is likely just a spelling error; if the distance is three or more, it's either a very poorly spelled answer, or an incorrect answer (both should be counted as incorrect).

The wikipedia article linked above has pseudocode implementation for the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks your the reply. Yea comparing the lengths between String is more of an ideal solution, rather than regex's. I'l look into that algorithm. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The first regex to match: Elephants
If it doesn't match try Eleph[ae]nt for the second.
If also not, try Elephant.

You could additionally combine it with word end markers.

For testing regexes, this site is really cool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

With regexs, you have to try to guess the spelling errors..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'l look into that site

Answer (score 0):

1. Fully Correct Regex:

   "Elephants"
2. Correct although spelled "Elephants" Regex:
   "[^E]lephants|E[^l]ephents|El[^e]phants|Ele[^p]hants|Elep[^h]ants|Eleph[^a]nts|Elepha[^n]ts|Elephan[^t]s|Elephant[^s]"
3. Answer accepted Regex:
   "lephants|Eephants|Elphants|Elehants|Elephants|Elephnts|Elephnts|Elephats|Elephans|Elephant"

You could write a small program which automatically generates the regexp which validate your answer and outputs you the case in which your regexp fall

- Correct
- Correct although misspelled
- Answer accepted

For instance, assuming that the correct answer is "Elephants", you could write a routine which test for the second case (Correct although misspelled).

```
String generateCorrectAltoughMispelledAnswerRegex(final String answer) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String answer = "Elephants";
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        String mispelled = answer.substring(0, i) + "[^" + char.at(i) + "]" + 
            (i < length ? answer.substring(i + 1) : "");
        answer.append(mispelled);
        if (i < length - 1) { answer.append("|"); }
    }
    String regex = builder.build();
    return regex;
}
```

e.g.: By calling the function generateCorrectAlthoughMispelledAnswerRegex with the argument "Elephants"
    generateCorrectAltoughMispelledAnswerRegex("Elephants")

it will generate the regexp to the test for the second case:

```
"[^E]lephants|E[^l]ephents|El[^e]phants|Ele[^p]hants|Elep[^h]ants|Eleph[^a]nts|Elepha[^n]ts|Elephan[^t]s|Elephant[^s]"
```

You can do the same for the other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I could do that, but i'd have to do that for the 150 Strings I have for the quiz :S. That would be a nightmare. But thanks again

Comment: OK thanks. That's a really good solution. I'l see out I can implement this method in my program.
Thanks, much appreciated